# Debugging IIS - not working?

Tags: iis

I can't connect to the localhost iis, even though it seems to be setup okay.  What should I look for?

Answer (score 1):

check event log for errors

Check that the www service is running

check that the site is not stopped inside IIS admin console

Check which ip and port it is listening

Check you don't have a firewall that block traffic